# c++:return statement behaving weirdly

Tags: c++

Here is an outline of the code containing the relevant part of my code.

Inside the empprint function i call a bfs print function, which calls itself recursively till its done printing everything that needs to be printed, after which its supposed to return me back to empprint function. But the return statement in bfsprint doesn't take me back to empprint.

One possible reason I can think of is that bfsprint calls itself recursively so it will only return to the last bfsprint method that called it instead of empprint function but it doesnt seem to solve my problem. I m stuck up with a code whose execution doesnt terminate.

```
void node::empprint(node* myroot)
{
    //do something
    bfsprint(c);
    cout<<"pt 5"; //this cout is not reached
    return;
}

void node::bfsprint(Linklist<node*> noddy)
{
    // lot of code to implement breadth-first search. No issue

    if(c.getHead()==NULL) cout<<"1" //this does print 1 to output
    if(c.getHead()==NULL) return; //I think this should send me back to empprint
                                  // and print "pt 5" on output but program hangs.
                                  // instead of this happening
    bfsprint(c);
}
```

If anybody thinks this might be influenced by other code in the method , I will add it but I dont think its the case.

Comment: It just sends you back to the last `bfsprint` call as long it was called from there.

Comment: Thought so. Is there a neat direct way to go to empprint?

Comment: Well, if the code is really as you show (i.e. the only recursive code to `bfsprint()` is at the very end of the function), then that's good enough and it should return. Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: It's pretty direct, just winding back the stack through all the recursive calls.

Comment: What's `c` in `bfsprint` ? Post a compilable code!

Comment: @uchiaitachi, Actual compilable code is 600 line so i posted only the code relevant to my problem and i got an answer. Thankyou !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your call stack looks like:

```
node::empprint
node::bfsprint
node::bfsprint
```

then returning from the final call will result in

```
node::empprint
node::bfsprint
```

So your still N calls deep away from getting back to node::empprint.

You could set a bool in the class to return back out, but thats a bit hacky..

```
void node::bfsprint(Linklist<node*> noddy)
{
   if ( something ) { m_unwindstack = true; }

   // setting the bool to force returning early/stop recursion once m_unwindstack  is true to get back to empprint
   if ( m_unwindstack ) { return; }
}
```

Edit: By the way if you're doing anything with Linklist you'll never seen the changes since your passing a copy of the data. You should pass a reference Linklist&.

Also Linklist seems like your own class? So if you don't use a reference then be sure its copyable otherwise bad things will happen.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer.
That is right. I will pass a reference and add a copy constructor for it. I m new to c++ programming and trying to do too much too early so it gets tough to manage.

Comment: Its best to use a const reference if you're not going to change the data too, saves needless copys of the data.